# How to avoid docker toolbox IP invalid certs?

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I am tesing docker on Windows 7 machine by installing docker toolbox.
It works for a while. Then its IP changed from 192.168.99.100 to 192.168.99.101.
When I run `$docker image ls`. It tells me that my certs is signed by unknown authority.

I resolved this by running `$docker-machine regenerate-certs` and then copy those files from .docker/machines/machine/default to .docker/machine/certs. It recovers.

But the problem is, the IP changes every now and then. I have to go through this process all over again.

Is there a way to config and avoid this from happening?